# Разбивка текста на разные составляющие

Tags: javascript

Есть строка, которая имеет вид

> Some text tag=Tag for this text, second tag, scope= some scope, scope2

Нужно разбить этот текст на строку и массив вида `{Key,Value}` где `Key` - это то значение, что идеть перед `=`, а `Value` - это список разделенный запятой.
То есть в результате должно получится:

```
queryText = "Some text"   

 parameters = {
 [Key:tag;   Value:Tag for this text],
 [Key:tag;   Value:second tag],
 [Key:scope; Value:some scope],
 [Key:scope; Value:some scope2]
 }
```

Я сделал так :

```
var query = queryString.val().trim().split(" ");
var queryText = query[0];
        if(query.length > 1)
        {
            var itm = 1;
            var currScope = "";
            for(itm; itm < query.length; itm ++)
            {               
                if(query[itm].indexOf("=") > -1)
                {                    
                    var filterVal = query[itm].split("=");
                    currScope = filterVal[0];
                    var keys = filterVal[1].split(",");

                    for(var k in keys)
                    {
                        if(keys[k])
                        {
                            this.parameters.push({ Key: currScope, Value: keys[k] });
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(currScope)
                    {
                        this.parameters.push({ Key: currScope, Value: query[itm]});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Но такая реализация работает только если в `queryString` все фразы без словосочетаний, то есть по одной фразе, без пробелов.

Как правильно расширить реализацию?

Comment: `key` не может включать в себя пробелы?

Comment: может. у меня не получается правильно разбить строку, чтобы запихнуть словосочетания в массив. Исправил

Comment: тогда я не совсем понял почему в пример в вопросе _"Some text"_ ушло в _queryText_, а не в [Key:Some text tag;

Comment: потому что Some text - это просто текст, а все, что идет после tag= - должно идти в массив. tag - это Key, также, как и scope. в смысле все что идет после = должно записываться в массив, где Key должно быть то значение, которое перед =. Это значений будет будет без пробелов, одна фраза.

Comment: А почему key именно `tag`? есть какой-то список ключей?

Comment: попробуйте найти ваши кеи регулярным варажением [a-z]{1,}\= , а потом уже разбивайте строку

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, а `=` зачем экранировать? ну и это судя по всему не подходит, так как в ответе на мой комментарий ТС сказал, что ключи могут включать пробелы

Comment: @Grundy, ) на всякий случай.

Comment: возможно подойдет следующая [регулярка](https://regex101.com/r/pJ2yM4/1)

Comment: Попробовал через RegExp.
Сделал так:

 var queries = queryString.val().trim();
 var rex = new RegExp("([^\s]+=[^=]+)(?![^\s])","g");
 var matchArr = queries.match(rex);
 
 в matchArr 2 элемента 
 0-"Some text tag=Tag for this text, second tag "
 1-"cope= some scope, scope2"
 Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так.

```
function parseQuery:(queryText, searchParameter){

        var queryText = queries.split(" ");
        var newQuerytext= '';
        for (var q in queryText)
        {
            if (queryText[q].indexOf("=") > -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            newQuerytext = newQuerytext + ' ' + queryText[q];
        }
        var scopesArray = [];       
        var rex = new RegExp("([" + searchParameter + "]+=[^=]+)(?![^\\s])", "g");

        var matchArr = rex.exec(queryText);
        if(matchArr !== null && matchArr.length > 0)
        {
            var query = matchArr[0];
            var vals = query.split("=");

            var values = vals[1].split(",");
            for(var v in values)
            {
                scopesArray.push({Key: searchParameter, Value: values[v]});
            }
        }
    }
```